# Shadowing parameter in Python functions

Tags: python, variables, parameters, scope, arguments

I've got myself a bit confused regarding variables in Python, just looking for a bit of clarification.

In the following code, I will pass a global variable into my own Python function which simply takes the value and multiplies it by 2. Very simple. It does not return the variable after. The output from the print function at the end prints 10500 rather than 21000, indicating that the local variable created within the function did not actually edit the global variable that was passed to, but rather used the value as its argument.

```
balance = 10500

def test(balance):
    balance = balance * 2

test(balance)
print(balance)
```

However, in my second piece of code here, when I pass a list/array into a separate function for bubble sorting, it is the actual array that is edited, rather than the function just using the values.

```
def bubble_sort(scores):
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(0, len(scores)-1):
            if scores[i] > scores[i+1]:
                temp = scores[i]
                scores[i] = scores[i+1]
                scores[i+1] = temp
                swapped = True

scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54]

bubble_sort(scores)
print(scores)
```

Now when I print my scores list, it has been sorted. I am confused as to why the top function did not change the global variable that was passed to it, while the second function did? I understand using the global keyword within functions means I am still able to write code that will edit a global variable within my own functions, but maybe I am missing some basic understanding.

Comment: You're getting the relationship between variables and objects mixed up. Have a [quick guide to how that works](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: A variable holds a reference to an object. In the first case you change the stored reference to another object. In the second case you modify the object which is referenced by local and global variable independently.

Comment: user2357112 that guide was very helpful, thank you very much. Thanks to you to Michael, also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is about mutability.

Ints are immutable. When you assign balance initially, because it is an int, the value of balance won't change unless you reassign it. You know this, because you reassign it in your definition. However, the confusion in your situation is because there are actually two "balance" variables. The global one, and the one that exists inside your function each time you call. The assignment that happens within your function does not actually affect the assignment of the global variable. It doubly isn't really doing anything because there's no return value.

To actually change things, you would want

```
def test(balance):
    balance = balance * 2
    return balance

balance = test(balance)
```

The list situation is different because lists are actually mutable. This makes it so that when you're changing values in scores, you're really changing values in scores. And so when you call your function on it, it changes things without the need for reassignment.

This is generally a situation of remembering the inherent properties of the data types in python. Certain things are mutable and certain things are not. You can probably google up a quick chart, and the more you work in python, remembering the differences becomes second nature.

Comment: That's really well explained ayluo, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

In both functions, the global variable is shadowed by the local variable.

In the test function, the global and local variables start by pointing to the same value, but the local variable is reassigned to another value.

In the bubble_sort function, the global and local variables also start by pointing to the same value.  This time, instead of reassigning the local variable to a new value, you mutate the object it is pointing to.  If in the bubble_sort function you reassigned the local variable, you would end up with a similar outcome to your test function.

Comment: Thanks jfogus. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you will need to access some shadowed **global variable** inside your function, it could be achieved by using `globals()` function. It returns the `dict`, so the variable could be accessed via the key that equals to the shadowed variable name. For example:

```
a = 10


def foo():
    a = 1 # the global variable 'a' was shadowed
    print(a) # the same as locals()['a']
    print(globals()['a']) # accessing global variable


foo()
```

It will return:

```
1
10
```